# How to post values from checkboxes generated from an ArrayList to another objects ArrayList with form in Thymeleaf and Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a form that takes several inputs from the user to create an object and one of these inputs are a set of checkboxes.

The checkboxes are generated from a `Model` with an `ArrayList` with `Grape` objects called **"GrapeList"** but I can't manage to figure out how to add them to the object that is created when submitting the form.

My form looks like this:

```
<form class="col-12" action="#" th:action="@{/admin}" th:object="${Wine}" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1">
                <label for="nameInput">Name: </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-11">
                <input class="w-100" id="nameInput" type="text" th:field="*{name}">
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                <label for="descriptionInput">Description: </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-11">
                <textarea class="w-100" id="descriptionInput" type="text" th:field="*{description}"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
====================PROBLEM=======================
        <div class="row" th:each="grape: ${GrapeList}">
            <div class="col">
                <label th:for="'grape' + ${grape.name}" th:text="${grape.name}"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input type="checkbox" th:id="'grape' + ${grape.name}" th:value="${grape.id}" th:field="*{grapes.add()}">
            </div>
        </div>
====================PROBLEM=======================

        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" value="Submit">Save</button>
    </form>
```

The form is creating a `Wine` Object that has an `ArrayList` with `Grape` Objects called **"grapes"**. The other input fields works fine but I dont know how to bind the arraylist to add a grape object for every checked box..
The `th:field="*{grapes.add()}"` is just there to describe what I'm trying to do..

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add `name` attribute to your generated checboxes, for example **"grape"**. Therefore they all will be generated with same name. When form with such checkboxes is submitted browser sends values for chosen name repeatedly for every selected checkbox, like

   `grape=first&grape=third&grape=extra`
2. Capture this data in your controller. This can be done in several ways.

   - Get parameters directly from `HttpServletRequest`:

     ```
     @RequestMapping(path="/admin", method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public void formSubmitted(HttpServletRequest request){
       Map<String, String[]> allParams = request.getParameterMap(); // fetch all params 
       String[] grapes = request.getparameterValues("grape");       // or just grapes
     }
     ```
   - Use `@RequestParam` annotation

     ```
     @RequestMapping(path="/admin", method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public void formSubmitted(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> allParams,
                               @RequestParam(name="grape", optional=true) List<String> grapes){
       // your code
     }
     ```
   - Not absolutely sure if it's possible to map this construct directly to object's field, but it seems you can tweak Spring MVC to do this.

Comment: Thanks alot! This worked! Follow-up question: Is it better to use ```@RequestMapping``` in conjunction with ```method=RequestMethod.POST``` instead of just ```@PostMapping```?

Comment: if POST is the only method to use for controller method - then both options are equivalent